# How can I pass multiple sub-commands to xargs when using the parallel option

Tags: bash, find, xargs

I'm trying to write a bash script to process a large directory tree and rsync that in multiple streams. From other research on this site I constructed the following. The assumption is the command is run:

program.sh /input/location /output/location $threads

The key line in my script is

```
cd $1; find . -depth \( -type d -printf \""%p/\"\n" \) | xargs -n1 -P$3 -I% rsync -lptgoDds --delete --backup --backup-dir=$INCREMENTALS/$DATE/$1 % $2/%
```

The idea of the above is to find all the directories at a certain point and then pass them to parallel instances of an rsync command to copy the data from $1 to $2.

The issue I am having is rsync may have to create nested folders that don't yet exist depending on how the inputs are parsed. (At least I think that's the cause of the errors I'm seeing). To get around this I thought I could issue two commands within the rsync. The first command would make the directory, the second would start the rsync.

Something like this:

```
cd $1; find . -depth \( -type d -printf \""%p/\"\n" \) | xargs -n1 -P$3 -I% 'mkdir -p %;rsync -lptgoDdsv --delete % $2/%;'
```

But that doesn't seem to work either.

So having played with this for some time now, I'm reaching out for help. :-)

Comment: In what way is it not working exactly? Are you getting errors?

Comment: It would be better to use `-exec` option with `find` instead of `xargs`.

Comment: Yes I was getting errors with "directory not found" because I think sub-directories are being processed sometimes before the higher level ones. I did however take off -depth from the find and that may have fixed it.

I don't want to use -exec because I want the parallel processing of xargs with the -P function.

Comment: @ChrisHarvey Not sure if intentional, but it seems that without a `-prune` option for `-find` you're also going to have subidrectories processed by rsync multiple times. And I don't think the parentheses and `-printf` are needed here at all. Also, consider posting an answer if you've got your command sorted out.

Comment: @BroSlow  I haven't noticed the results being processed multiple times yet. I think that's being handled by the -n1 on xargs. The whole (type -d -printf) thing was just to get the input to have double quotes around it so it can handle odd characters like spaces etc..

If anyone has a better suggestion on that, it's welcomed.

Comment: I've simplified my code a little but still struggling with handing two commands to xargs. Now the main line reads:

    cd $SRCDIR; find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P$THREADS -I% rsync -lptgoDdv % $TARGETDIR/%

Find and list all directories. 

When my input list is very long, I see errors with directory not found, so I *think* rsync is building directories not yet created. I want to insert a mkdir -p to force the creation.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a complex command in single quotes to `xargs` like that. But you can pass it to `sh`, and pass that to `xargs`.

```
cd $1; find . -depth \( -type d -printf \""%p/\"\n" \) | xargs -n1 -P$3 -I% sh -c 'mkdir -p %;rsync -lptgoDdsv --delete % $2/%;'
```

(I have no way to test this. It might still need some adaptation.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the example from GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example__parallelizing_rsync is pretty close to what you want:

```
cd src-dir; find . -type f -size +100000 | parallel -v ssh fooserver mkdir -p /dest-dir/{//}\;rsync -Havessh {} fooserver:/dest-dir/{}
```

Instead this ought to work:

```
cd $1; find . -depth -type d | parallel -P$3 mkdir -p $INCREMENTALS/$DATE/$1 $2/{}\; rsync -lptgoDds --delete --backup --backup-dir=$INCREMENTALS/$DATE/$1 {} $2/{}
```

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your system, this should install it in 10 seconds:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

To learn more: Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). You command line
will love you for it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to come back and re-post what I think is the answer. I had to use a shell invocation to do what I needed to do and after a lot of trial and error it occurred to me the answer was pretty simple to pass the fields down to the sub-shell. By exporting them, they become available to the sub-shells and it works like a charm. Here's my current script.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

export INCREMENTALS="/var/backup/data"
export DATE=`date +%F`
export SRCDIR=$1
export TARGETDIR=$2
export THREADS=$3


cd $SRCDIR; find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P$THREADS -I {} sh -c 'echo $TARGETDIR/"{}"; mkdir -p $TARGETDIR/"{}"; rsync -lptgoDdXvz --delete --backup --backup-dir=$INCREMENTALS/$DATE/.$SRCDIR "{}"/ $TARGETDIR/"{}"'
```

To run the script you use this sequence:

```
rsync.sh /from/dir /to/dir 20
```

The first two parameters are obvious, the "20" is the number of threads of rsync you want to invoke.

So this way you are pushing many parallel rsync's to the point of exhausting the machine. The only gotcha I've found is that if there are directories with many thousands of files the parallelism falls apart because all the others finish and you are stuck waiting behind the longest one. I'm trying to work out a way to do more of a spray approach now for round II.

My only other issue now is my memory consumption goes up over time. I have a funny feeling there's a leak that's not related to my script, but I'm concerned I may have some unbounded element in this which is causing constant ever increasing memory use. Still that's another problem to solve, unrelated to this.

The net-net answer was to 'export' the functions and then the sub-shells see the content correctly and it works really well.