# Protecting input to bash for directories with odd characters and also single quotes

Tags: bash

I'm struggling with protecting some input to a bash/rsync script. In short I'm trying to navigate rsync'ing some directories and the issue I'm running into is that some of the directories may have odd characters like a `$` sign and others have single quotes `'`.

I've found if I protect the variables in the input with `""` then the `$ABC` directory get's protected and handled correctly, but the directories with a single quote do not. Conversely, if I protect them with a single quote the `$ABC` fails but the directories with a single quote work.

I've tried stacking the quotes and single quotes around my variables in different ways, but in each case there's a different error and I cannot cater to both the variables and the single quotes in the input stream with the same solution.

Here's the code snippet that I'm working with:

```
cd $SRCDIR; find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P$THREADS -I {} bash -c 'echo $TARGETDIR/"'{}'"; mkdir -p $TARGETDIR/"'{}'"; rsync -lptgoDdvXsz "'{}'"/ $TARGETDIR/"'{}'"'
```

In this configuration, it transfers directories that have single quotes such as:

```
/data/here's my photos/
```

But won't transfer the contents of:

```
/data/$ABC
```

If I reverse the single quotes and double quotes around, I get the opposite behavior but I'm struggling to get both to work.

I checked out this thread: [Problems with single quotes in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637643/problems-with-single-quotes-in-a-bash-script)  but stacking the quotes in either direction didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `xargs` will replace the `{}` itself, there's no need to leave them out of the quotes; the following is equivalent, but easier to follow. (And, as Etan points out, it's better to let the resulting script accept the string from `xargs` as an argument, rather than including `{}` in the script itself.

```
cd $SRCDIR
find . -type d -print0 | 
  xargs -0 -n1 -P$THREADS bash -c '
    echo "$TARGETDIR/$1"
    mkdir -p "$TARGETDIR/$1"
    rsync -lptgoDdvXsz "$1/" "$TARGETDIR/$1"' -
```

Now, since the `bash` command will get `$TARGETDIR` literally (because it is inside single quotes), just make sure that variable is exported to the `bash` command's environment with the redundant-looking

```
TARGETDIR=$TARGETDIR xargs -0 -n1 ...
```

This sets the value of `TARGETDIR` in the environment `xargs` will run in, which is inherited by each of the eventual calls to `bash`.

And my usual advice: if you are using `bash` 4, skip `find` and just use a for-loop that takes advantage of the globstar operator. It will be more efficient, since you don't need to start a new instance of `bash` for each directory, and the shell's expansion of `**/*` should not be significantly less efficient than using `find`.

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for d in "$SRCDIR"/**/*/; do
    echo "$TARGETDIR/$d"
    mkdir -p "$TARGETDIR/$d"
    rsync -lptgoDdvXsz "$d/" "$TARGETDIR/$d"
done
```

Comment: Double quotes in filenames will blow that up as they are literally injected into the script (this is your comment about `{}` exactly). This is why you pass the filename to the script as an argument and use `$0` or `$1` in the script.

Comment: Gah, you're right. I need to stop answering questions involving `bash -c` :)

Comment: I don't usually use `xargs`, but I think I've edited the answer to pass the filename correctly.

Comment: I use `xargs` semi-regularly and while I don't usually use `sh -c`/etc. with it I have in the past and didn't think about the quoting/etc. issues until I saw someone on here mention it as a comment on an answer. At which point I was amazed I hadn't thought of it before.

Comment: I added the padding `-` argument to the `bash -c` invocation so the argument is `$1` instead of `$0`. =)

Comment: Yeah. It is an odd detail to need to remember.

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look at this today and see if it helps. I am indeed exporting the variables further up in the script so the variable paths I issue on the command line are inherited to the sub-shells. That took me a while to work out and is the context of this question I posted before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598586/how-can-i-pass-multiple-sub-commands-to-xargs-when-using-the-parallel-option

Comment: I've been looking at this and I love the way it list the directories and deals with the rsync. So for the posed question I think that's the answer.

The problem (which isn't related to this question) is I really need the rsync to be parallel which is why I had xargs in the first place. Serially walking the tree doesn't get me enough parallel threads to complete the job quickly enough. But I'm thinking of using this method to build a tree which a subsequent job then walks in a parallel way. 

So thanks guys, this was awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
escapedFilename=$(printf '%q' "$filename")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a method of protection, but you can do the two commands depending on on the presence of a`'`. This is probabbly not as good of a solution as above, but the logic is quite simple.

```
if [[ $ABC == *'* ]]
then
  do the command for if there is a ';
else
  do the command if there is not a ';
fi
```